# Erlang rb module

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

When looking up messages in a sasl log using `rb:list()` or `rb:show()`, rb seems to dump the output in the console and return 'ok'; is there any way to configure rb to get it to return the actual log message ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the following function, which dumps the logs to a temporary file and reads that file:

```
get_logs(LogDir) ->
    TmpFile = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("log_tmp_~B_~B_~B", tuple_to_list(now()))),
    try
        % Make the report browser write logs to a temporary file.
        % We use rb:start_link instead of rb:start, to not depend on the sasl
        % application being started.
        {ok, _} = rb:start_link([{start_log, TmpFile},
                                 {report_dir, LogDir}]),
        rb:show(),
        % We catch errors from stopping, since we're going to get one
        % if sasl isn't started.  (UTSL)
        catch rb:stop(),
        % Ouch... let's hope the logs fit in memory.
        case file:read_file(TmpFile) of
            {ok, Logs} ->
                Logs;
            {error, Error} ->
                io_lib:format("Couldn't read logs: ~p", [Error])
        end
    catch _:E ->
            io_lib:format("Couldn't read logs: ~p", [E])
    after
        file:delete(TmpFile)
    end.
```